# Unit test componentDidMount React

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

Learning react jest and enzyme trying to unit test some stuff that I dont know how to here is what I have and what I have tried

I am not sure how to test the object that I am sending and also I want to test the if else condition where the object that I am sending changes based on the flag.

Any idea how I can test const a1 and const 1 the await providers

```
async componentDidMount() {
    
    await this.loadLogin();
    const a1 = await providers.login();
    const b1 = await providers.reset();
    const flag = true;
        
    if (flag !== null) {
        analytics.sendEvent({
            event: {
                workflow: "a1",
                subcategory: "f1",
                type: "enabled",
            },
        });
    } else {
        analytics.sendEvent({
            event: {
                workflow: "b1",
                subcategory: "f2",
                type: "disabled",
            },
        });
    }
}
```

Unit test so far

```
test("componentDidMount", async () => {
    wrapper = mount(component());
    const instance = wrapper.instance();
    instance.componentDidMount();

    const obj = {
        event: {
            workflow: "a1",
            subcategory: "f1",
            type: "enabled",
        },
    };

    const flag = jest.fn();
    flag.mockReturnValue(true);
    analytics.sendEvent = jest.fn();
    expect(flag).toBeTruthy();
    expect(analytics.sendEvent).toBeCalledWith(expect.objectContaining(obj));
    expect(wrapper).toHaveLength(1);
});
```

Getting error

```
expect(jest.fn()).toBeCalledWith(...expected)

    Expected: ObjectContaining {"event": {"subcategory": "f1", "type": "enabled", "workflow": "a1"}}

    Number of calls: 0

       analytics.sendEvent = jest.fn();
      expect(flag).toBeTruthy();
    expect(analytics.sendEvent).toBeCalledWith(expect.objectContaining(obj));
         |                                     ^
       expect(wrapper).toHaveLength(1);
       });
```

Comment: try `await instance.componentDidMount();`, as your `componentDidMount` is asynchronous. Check out this link https://medium.com/@lucksp_22012/jest-enzyme-react-testing-with-async-componentdidmount-7c4c99e77d2d

Comment: what will that do just trying to learn

Answer (score 0):

Quite a few of mistakes, not sure if you understand enzyme enough:

- you can't modify an in-file variable (`const flag`, `analytics.sendEvent`) like you do, because in your test file these are just unrecognized by jest, however enzyme lets you modify component's state and of course props ( more on that later );
- if so, your first `expect` statement is pointless, it's tautological, because you just create a variable, assign a `true` to it, then test if it's `true`;
- also, your last `expect` is a mistery for me (are you testing if `enzyme` actually mounts a component as intended?);
- again, the fact that you create a variable with the name matching the variable that's inside your component (`const obj`) doesn't mean anything, it's like any other `js` file;
- `.toBeCalled()` accepts just an object, not an `expect` statement.

My advice is to use `axios-mock-adapter` to mock a url/method from your `adapter` and to test the actual `obj` that's in `else` block of your component:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import MockAdapter from 'axios-mock-adapter';

test("componentDidMount", async () => {
    const obj ={
        event: {
            workflow: "b1",
            subcategory: "f2",
            type: "disabled",
        },
    };

    const url = 'http://your/api/path'; // that's the url the obj is sent to at analytics.sendEvent
    const mock = new MockAdapter(axios);
    mock.onPost(url, obj)
            .reply(200, 'success');
    const spy = jest.spyOn(mock, 'onPost');

    wrapper = mount(component());
    const instance = wrapper.instance();
    instance.componentDidMount();
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(url, obj);
});
```